# Woocommerce checkout accordion jQuery not work

Tags: jquery, wordpress, accordion, woocommerce

On the Woocommerce checkout page iv tried to add an jQuery accordion to the shipping address section, the JS isnt working! works on other pages apart from this one...

any one got an idea how to fix?

Template HTML:

```
<h3 class="toggle-trigger" style="clear:none;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tr ">
        <?php _e( 'Shipping Address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
</h3>
<div class="toggle-container" style="display:none;">
    <div class="toggle-block"> ... content form ... </div></div>
```

JS code:

```
// Toggles
jQuery(".toggle-container").hide();
jQuery(".toggle-trigger").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle(100);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Any errors? Do you see if the handler is getting invoked at all? Is this inside document.ready?

Comment: @PSL yes its inside doc.ready am not sure how to check if its getting invoked ?

Comment: You need to use element id/class that will toggle here in place of 'this' .
In your case

`jQuery(.toggle-container).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle(100);`